# Read .html files from the next.js react public/assets and format it with tailwind.css

Tags: reactjs, tailwind-css, next.js13

I'm learning next.js with React with tailwind css and was looking to read html static files from the public/assets folder:

```
import React from 'react';
import fs from 'node:fs';

import parse from 'node-html-parser';

const HTMLComponent = ({ filename }  : string) => {

  try {
    const htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(`./public/assets/html/${filename}`, 'utf-8');

    return (
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: htmlContent }} />
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error reading file: ${err}`);
  }
 
};

export default HTMLComponent;
```

I then use the component like this:

```
import HTMLComponent from '@/components/shared/HTMLFile';
export default function Page() {

  return (
    <div className='p-4'>

    <HTMLComponent filename = "index.html" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Even though the index.html is formatted with h1, p and so on; none of that css formatting shows up in the displayed page.

I suspect that dangerouslySetInnerHTML is my nemesis.

Is there a better way to do this and get properly formatted css'd html?

The page has a header (which should import tailwind css)
layout and footer.  The included HTMLComponent is rendered on the page as all < p >s even though there are < h1 > tags present.
The generated css has classes like:

```
@media (min-width: 768px) {

  .h1 {
    font-size: 36px;
    line-height: 44px;
  }
}
```

Your answers are much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`dangerouslySetInnerHTML` only allows you to insert raw HTML into a component, it doesn't automatically apply styling from external CSS to the inserted HTML content.

Try parsing the HTML content using `node-html-parser` to extract specific elements and apply Tailwind classes directly in your React component:

```
import React from 'react';
import parse from 'node-html-parser';

const HTMLComponent = ({ filename }) => {
  const parsedHTML = parse(fs.readFileSync(`./public/assets/html/${filename}`, 'utf-8'));
  const h1Element = parsedHTML.querySelector('h1');

  return (
    <div>
      <h1 className="text-3xl font-bold">{h1Element.text}</h1>
      {/* Other elements with Tailwind classes */}
    </div>
  );
};
```

If the external HTML files contain their own CSS, import those css flies within your component using next/head:

```
import Head from 'next/head';

const HTMLComponent = ({ filename }) => {
  const htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(`./public/assets/html/${filename}`, 'utf-8');
  const parsedHTML = parse(htmlContent);
  const cssLinks = parsedHTML.querySelectorAll('link[rel="stylesheet"]');

  return (
    <div>
      <Head>
        {cssLinks.map((link) => (
          <link key={link.href} rel="stylesheet" href={link.href} />
        ))}
      </Head>
      <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: parsedHTML.body.innerHTML }} />
    </div>
  );
};
```

Also consider rendering the HTML files on the server using Next.js's SSR capabilities:

```
// In a page component or API route
export async function getStaticProps() {
  const htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(`./public/assets/html/index.html`, 'utf-8');

  return {
    props: {
      renderedHTML: htmlContent,
    },
  };
}

export default function Page({ renderedHTML }) {
  return (
    <div dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: renderedHTML }} />
  );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you know what the class names will be, this is easy in your custom css file.

You can use tailwind as follows:

```
.class-name {
  @apply bg-white text-sm etc...
}
```

https://tailwindcss.com/docs/reusing-styles#extracting-components-and-partials

Comment: I ended up adding specific css to the article making use of the tailwind classes:

  <h3 class="h2-bold flex-2 align-top p-4">1. Protect Your Personal Information</h3>

Answer (score 1):

It is not a problem of `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` but the problem is that the tailwind has over ridden it.
and to fix it you can use use an `iframe` rather than a `div` like this:

```
import React from 'react';
import fs from 'node:fs';

import parse from 'node-html-parser';

const HTMLComponent = ({ filename }  : string) => {

  try {
    const htmlContent = fs.readFileSync(`./public/assets/html/${filename}`, 'utf-8');

    return (
      <iframe srcDoc={htmlContent } />
    );
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(`Error reading file: ${err}`);
  }
 
};

export default HTMLComponent;
```

This should fix the issue. I hope it helps :)